# Can I include a view in Kohana 3 that is not within `application/views`?

Tags: php, view, kohana, kohana-3

I am building a staff area for a website, which is completely different to the main brochure style site.

I have 2 Kohana systems setup. I realise they can both share the same `system` and `modules` folder.

Now, with the second one, I want to make the main template view a view in a different folder.

I tried this in my base controller

```
$this->template = DOCROOT . '../~new2/application/views/template.php';
```

But Kohana is looking for it in its own `views` folder as evident by the error I received. I even put a `var_dump(file_exists($this->template)); // true` to be sure it was finding the correct file.

Is there a way to add a template file that is not within the `views` folder, without hacking the core Kohana code (and if I'm lucky not extending and overloading the view class).

Comment: If the server is using Linux you can create a symbolic link to the template file.

Comment: @dusan Agreed, using a symlink is the cleanest way of doing this. Create the following symlink 'application/views/staffarea' => '../~new2/application/views/template.php'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite *hacky*, but knowing that it is looking in the `views` folder, you can point to your view like so.

```
$this->template = '../../../~new2/application/views/template';

$path = APPPATH . 'views/' . $this->template;


var_dump(realpath($path)); // proper path

var_dump(file_exists($path)); // true
```

Yeah, it's ugly. But it **works**.